# Is it possible to load this xml with sqlxmlbulkload?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, sqlxml

Is it possible to load a similar xml into these tables with sqlxmlbulkload?
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
    <b>
    <code>1</code>
    <ds1>1.11</ds1>
    <ds1>1.12</ds1>
    <ds1>1.13</ds1>
    <ds2>2.11</ds2>
    </b>

    <b>
    <code>2</code>  
    <ds1>1.21</ds1>
    <ds1>1.22</ds1>
    <ds2>2.21</ds2>
    <ds2>2.22</ds2>
    </b>

    <b>
    <code>3</code>      
    <ds1>1.31</ds1>
    <ds2>2.31</ds2>
    <ds2>2.32</ds2>
    </b>

    <b>
    <code>4</code>      
    <ds2>2.41</ds2>
    </b>
</a>
```

Sql server tables:

```
Create table b
    ([_id_b] int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,[code] nvarchar(10) NULL
    ,Constraint PK_b primary key clustered ([_id_b])
    )
;
Create table ds
    ([_id_ds] int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,[_id_b] int NOT NULL
    ,[ds] nvarchar(10) NULL
    ,[type] smallint not null constraint cs_type check ([type] between 1 and 2)
    ,Constraint PK_ds primary key clustered ([_id_ds])
    )
```

What should xsd schema be for this xml for sqlxmlbulkload?
This is not an easy question!
Note, I need to load the tags `<ds1>` and `<ds2>` into one table ds, and these are multiple tags.
It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following statement you will pull the values out of your XML. Storing this result within your tables should be rather simple:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<a>
    <b>
    <code>1</code>
    <ds1>1.11</ds1>
    <ds1>1.12</ds1>
    <ds1>1.13</ds1>
    <ds2>2.11</ds2>
    </b>

    <b>
    <code>2</code>  
    <ds1>1.21</ds1>
    <ds1>1.22</ds1>
    <ds2>2.21</ds2>
    <ds2>2.22</ds2>
    </b>

    <b>
    <code>3</code>      
    <ds1>1.31</ds1>
    <ds2>2.31</ds2>
    <ds2>2.32</ds2>
    </b>

    <b>
    <code>4</code>      
    <ds2>2.41</ds2>
    </b>
</a>';
```

--The query

```sql
SELECT A.b.value('(code/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS b_code
      ,B.ds.value('text()[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS ds_value
      ,B.ds.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)') AS NodeName
FROM @xml.nodes('/a/b') AS A(b)
CROSS APPLY A.b.nodes('*[substring(local-name(),1,2)="ds"]') AS B(ds)
```

The result

```
b   ds      NodeName
1   1.1100  ds1
1   1.1200  ds1
1   1.1300  ds1
1   2.1100  ds2
2   1.2100  ds1
2   1.2200  ds1
2   2.2100  ds2
2   2.2200  ds2
3   1.3100  ds1
3   2.3100  ds2
3   2.3200  ds2
4   2.4100  ds2
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution is interesting. But, unfortunately, I needed sqlxmlbulkload :-(

Comment: @PeterJanvarev wow, 4 years later 

Comment: You can bulk-load the xml as text and proceed with this...